# Complex conveyor capacity calculation (graph) - fun game algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am working on a game in Javascript where people can create conveyor lines. Imagine postal service, packages come in, travel on conveyors, get processed and end in trucks. These conveyors can be of any complexity, can contain loops etc.

Example of a rather complex (and inefficient) conveyor
[Example conveyor with bad graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/047W0.png)

[image: Example conveyor with bad graphics]

Example graph of a conveyor:
[Conveyor example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10cH.jpg)

[image: Conveyor example]

number in circle means current situation - number of packages on that conveyor "part".

**Rules:**

- IN components generate postal packages that are put to belt component.
- Belt component pushes postal packages to OUT components. OUT removes packages from the graph.
- Each component has MAX capacity it can hold at any given moment.
- There can be 0..N IN components. (if 0, there can be packages already on the conveyor)
- There can be 0..N OUT components. (if 0, meaning whole conveyor will get full)
- Calculations are tick based, meaning that "group of packages" can travel only one step at a time.
- Each merge distributes packages evenly. (so if two out going lines, then each gets packages/2)
- Each join accepts packages evenly. (so if two input lines, each can give max max/2 packages. )
- Packages DO NOT have identity, they are just total numbers.
- Packages can be split, so 1 package can become 0.5 and 0.5 packages. (so float as number type)

**Problem:**

How to solve such a graph fast in two steps:

1. Generate necessary data structure/graph (cache) (Performance: <200ms for 1000 elements). In reality only needs to be recalculated if setup changes before next package travel calculation.
2. Calculate package travel. (Performance: <20ms for 1000 elements)

**Some problematic solutions**

OPTION A: Solve per component. (for loop each component and solve based on current situation) Doesn't work, as loops, joins, merges cause situations that it doesn't move packages evenly as required. Also it doesn't honour rule, that "package" can travel only from one component to another. Based on loop order it may be that package gets to end immediately). Additionally, it may prefer only one input all the time, other one will be always blocked.

OPTION B: Calculate for every component what they want to do and find conflicts. (for example A and B want to push to C 10 packages EACH, but C can accept only 12 in total. Fix error, so A and B both can move only 6 each, meaning their stock will be at least 4 each for next tick. This may cause more errors, as A and B did not clear their content and they can accept less). Now find more errors and fix. Repeat until no errors or "max repeats reached" and just quick fix errors = So that it actually doesn't work as expected based on rules.
problem with this is, that I think it will get stuck for certain setup and may break.

OPTION C: Start from OUT elements and try to move packages out. Problems arise if loops are introduced or areas without OUT elements.

**Verdict**

I am stuck and don't even know what to google for, so all ideas are welcome :)
I figured it is a graph problem, but maybe there are other approaches.

Comment: What should happen if you have a 2-way merge feeding into a 2-way split, with one branch of the split feeding back into the merge? There'll be an exponentially decaying package fragment trapped in a loop. Do you want to represent arbitrarily tiny package fragments?

Comment: True, for these very small packages I would add hardcoded IF, if package size less than 0.1 for example, it will just drop it and forget about it. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you dont need the optimal solution to the problem, I think you could:

```
1. At the beginning, use a topological sort order of the graph, and "tag"
   each node with its position in that order so you have a criteria as to
    which node is better than others. The final node has the maximum "tag"
   (check link to learn more about topological sort, not hard)

2. Mark all nodes as not visited

3. Get the *node A* with max(tag) still not visited:

3.a. Get each *node B* that is a target from *node A* 
     (i.e. at the end of the arrow) starting from the one with maximum tag
     and finishing with the one with minimum tag:

3.a.a. push all packages from *node A* to *node B* until it is filled or 
       *node A* is empty.
```

You can find the topological sort definition and a bunch of algorithms in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Best of lucks :)